# Elasticsearch search Query

Tags: elasticsearch

The "wooden door" keyword should give only **wooden doors** in the results with fuzziness. related to **wooden** and **doors** should not be displayed. using elastic search query

Comment: You should update the title to something more specific.

Comment: And does `match_phraseˋ can solve your issue ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html